# Error: Call to a possibly undefined method getRegionNameForCountries through a reference with static type com.framework.model:CountryModel

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Trying to figure out why I can call this function from a instantiated version of this class.

The error I get is this:

```
Error: Call to a possibly undefined method getRegionNameForCountries through a reference with static type com.framework.model:CountryModel.
```

The error comes from this code:

```
public static function territoriesFunction( item:Object, column:DataGridColumn ):String
            {
                return RemoteModelLocator.getInstance().appModel.countryModel.getRegionNameForCountries( item.countriesAvailable ) + ' ('+ item.countriesAvailable.length.toString() + ')';
            }
```

The Class I'm trying to call the function from is here:

```
package com.framework.model
{
    import com.adobe.cairngorm.vo.IValueObject;
    import com.adobe.crypto.MD5;
    import com.vo.RegionVO;

    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

    public class CountryModel implements IValueObject
    {

            public static function getCountriesForRegion( regionName:String ):Array
            {
                    try
                    {
                            var result:Array = _dataModel[regionName];
                    }
                    catch(e:Error){}

                    result =  ( result )? result: _dataModel[CountryModel.WORLDWIDE];

                    return ObjectUtil.copy( result ) as Array;
            }


            public static function getRegionNameForCountries( countries:Array ):String
            {

                    if( !countries || !countries.length )
                    {
                            return CountryModel.WORLDWIDE;
                    }


                    countries.sortOn("name");


                    var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                            buffer.writeObject(countries);
                            buffer.position = 0;


                    var hash:String = MD5.hashBytes( buffer );

                    try
                    {
                            var regionName:String = _dataModel[hash];
                            return ( regionName && regionName.length )? regionName : CountryModel.CUSTOM;
                    }
                    catch( e:Error )
                    {

                    }

                    return CountryModel.CUSTOM;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems fine to me based on the code given. The problem must be somewhere else. Is RemoteModelLocator.getInstance().appModel.countryModel definitely of the type you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access static vars/method from the Class object itself (eg. `MyClass.method()`), or from within the class declaration (static or instantiated).

Here is a simplified example:

```
MyClass.staticFunction(); //allowed

var myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.staticFunction(); //NOT allowed

//inside the MyClass.as
this.staticFunctionInSameClass(); //allowed
```

What you are trying to do is access a static method from a reference to an instantiated object of that class.

To keep the same structure as you are currently doing, you either need to create a non static helper method in the class:

```
//CountryModel class
public function getRegionNameForCountriesHelper(countries:Array):String
{
    return getRegionNameForCountries(countries); //calls the static method
}
```

OR just access it on the class itself.

```
return CountryModel.getRegionNameForCountries(item.countriesAvailable, ....);
```

If the Class is not known ahead of time, you can do it by casting the instance as `Object`, then accessing the `constructor` property which returns a reference to the `Class`.

```
return (Object(RemoteModelLocator.getInstance().appModel.countryModel).constructor).getRegionNameForCountries(item.countriesAvailable, ...);
```

That way is very messy though, without compile time checking.

I would recommending either making the class static only (don't allow instantiation), or don't use static methods in it.   Without knowing what all those parts of your application are (eg. RemoveModelLocator, appModel) it's difficult to say what would be best for your circumstance.

Comment: When I remove static from all the functions and properties, I get tons of errors in other parts of my application that tell me I'm referencing other possibly unknown methods on that class?

Comment: Nobody here knows what other references you have.  Anywhere you do `CountryModel.getRegionNameForCountries` you'd have to change it if you took out the static keyword in it's definition.   If you don't want to or have time to refactor your application to make these methods not static, then do one of the two options I've suggested.

Comment: Ahh fair point my apologies. I'll look into creating some non static workaround for the two places that I'm getting an undefined method error now. When I remove static from the methods, the rest of the application blows up.

Comment: Why can't you just do `return CountryModel.getRegionNameForCountries( item.countriesAvailable ) + ' ('+ item.countriesAvailable.length.toString() + ')';` inside your `territoriesFunction`?

Comment: @Brian - Indeed, I assumed the Class wasn't known until run-time, but I suppose if that were actually the case why would they access that very specific method.